# Как правильно называть и создавать DTO

Tags: rest, dto, именование

Помогите разобраться с созданием DTO для методов сервисного слоя.
DTO становится так много, что я запутываюсь в их названиях, и получается где-то повторение кода.

Не могу найти какой-то шаблонный стиль для построения этих DTO. Как вот сущность конвертировать в DTO, если не вся ее информация мне нужна, а иногда вся бывает нужна?

Больше всего путаюсь давать им названия. Надеюсь нормально сформулировал вопрос.

Comment: а по пакетам не пробовали разложить? создать сначала пакет дто, а потом классифицировать по какому-то признаку (зависит от архитектуры проекта) и расталкивать по разным пакетам. перестанете путаться плюс меньше проблем с именованием

Answer (score 4):

Дто - это по сути мусорные классы, их можно создавать сколько угодно, для любой нужной тебе операции. Возьмем пример: есть у тебя сущность, user, с ней можно делать след. вещи: это регистрация нового юзера, логин юзера, и к примеру получить юзера. Для каждой операции, ты можешь например создать одно дто, со всеми полями и назвать его, например UserDto, и у тебя будет одно дто для работы с юзерами, и название UserDto об этом говорит. Но можешь например сделать дто, для каждой нужной тебе операции, UserRegDto, UserLogDto, UserGetDTo, и использовать каждое дто, для каждой операции, и получается, что нейминг сам за себя говорит, что UserRegDto используется для регистрации и т.д. Так же например, если есть сущность у которой только две операции, это создать и получить, в таком случае можно воспользовать неймингом по типу EntityRequest и EntityResponse, в зависимости от того принимаешь ли ты это дто или отдаешь. Как я уже обозначил в начале, дто это чисто мусорные классы и особо заморачиваться с неймингом не стоит.

Comment: Добавлю к ответу пару уточнений. В нейминге главное строго придеживаться набора правил, который сам и принял. Какой именно это набор правил - не суть важно. Можно взять например такой:
1. Создай отедльую папку для DTO. Внутри по одной папке для каждого типа сущности.
2. Имя каждого класса DTO должно содержать имя сущности, к которой он относится, имя http запроса к которому он относится и постфикс Request или Response.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное. я так и делал да. Просто появлялось ощущение что слишком все как то расплывчато. Когда особенно создаешь дто в котором надо использовать дто другой сущности и в ней другая дто другой сущности. Я прямые дто классы к сущности называю к Примеру BasicDtoUser. это вот прям копия грубо говоря сущности. А остальные по названию метода который их возвращает